# Process Hashes in Document Collections Mongoid

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongodb, hash, mongoid3

I have a web application where I'm storing the type of users as a hash field. and i have many collections. what would be the best way to process that hash field.

```
class Community
  include Mongoid::Document

  class UserRoles
    Admin = :a
    Moderator = :m
  end

  include Mongoid::Timestamps

  field :un, as: :username, type: String
  field :nm, as: :name, type: String

  field :suids, as: :special_user_ids, type: Hash
  has_and_belongs_to_many :users
end
```

Now there can be many communities, having many users, and each user having many moderators. So for Special users i'm storing it as hash.

Now how would i compute if the current user who has logged in, is he a moderator/admin of any of the communities

I tried this and obviously this doesnt work. It'll work if i have a single document to deal with. And my solution doesnt serve the purpose of why the hash is used in first place.

```
  #  suids = []
  #  @communities = Community.all
  #  suids << @community.special_user_ids.collect { |k, v| k }
  #  //code doesnt find special_user_ids as it has too many documents to deal with.
  #  communities_path(@community.id)
```

I have a working code to find all the admins/moderator of a given community.

```
def admins
    @community = Community.find(params[:id])
    @users = User.where(:id.in => @community.special_user_ids.collect { |k, v| k })
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the desired communities get the admins, then you can do

```
if admins.include?(current_user)
    # treat as admin
end
```

**Edit**

```
all_admins = Array.new
```

Get all commmuniteis

```
@communities = Community.all

@communities.each do |c_comm|
   all_admins.concat(User.where(:id.in => c_comm.special_user_ids.collect { |k, v| k }))
end

puts all_admins.include(current_user)?
```

Comment: But my question is how do i get the list of admins for all the communities ? as  `#  @communities = Community.all
  #  suids << @community.special_user_ids.collect { |k, v| k }` Throws an error, it obviously cant get key values from many distinct documents

Comment: It works, but is there any efficient way to play around with HASH ?